# Got stuck on Finding an orthonormal basis for the orthogonal complement

Tags: orthogonality, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

The problem is
Find an orthonormal{w_1, w_2} for the orthogonal complement of the subspace U given by

2x+y-2z=0

2y-x+2z+w=0

I can not reach out next step from here....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPpvu.png)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that the coefficient on $x$ in the second equation is $-1$, not $2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find (x, y, z, w) satisfying 2x+y-2z= 0 and 2y-x+2z+w=0 add the equations and eliminating z: x+ 3y+ w= 0. w= -x- 3y.  So (x, y, z, -x- 3y) is a general solution.  The set of all solutions is a three-dimensional subspace with basis {(1, 0, 0, -1), (0, 1, 0, -1), (0, 0, 1, 0)}.

The orthogonal complement is a one-dimensional subspace of vectors that have 0 dot product with each of those.
That is, if (x, y, z, w) is in the orthogonal subspace,
x- w= 0
y- w= 0
z= 0.
That is (x, x, 0, x)= x(1, 1, 0, 1).
The length of that is $x\sqrt{3}$.

Since that is one dimensional, "orthogonal" is not relevant.  in order to be "normalized" x must  be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.  The orthogonal subspace is has orthonormal basis $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}, 0, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Question, the prob ask two bases like w_1, w_2. Then what is the other basis beside (3√3,3√3,0,3√3)??